# How to have a popup read and display information from a GeoJson file (LEAFLET)

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, gis, mapbox

I am trying to make an interactive map of trails my company owns for my companies website.

I have markers displayed on all the trailheads and I want them to display a popup of certain information located inside of a GeoJson file.

Here is my HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Map</title>
  <!-- leaflet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="lib/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
  <!--Mapbox -->
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
  <script src="data/trailheads.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    #map {
      height: 400px;
    }
  </style>



</head>

<body>
  <h1> Map </h1>


  <div id="map"></div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([43.8476, 18.3564], 13);
    var trailheadsLayer = L.geoJson(trailheads)
      .bindPopup()
      .addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(trailheadsLayer.getBounds());
    L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/spatrick467/cj3yh6guz21os2so16xhs4son/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic3BhdHJpY2s0NjciLCJhIjoiTVNaNG1OWSJ9.gq6641R9QJG5jWyO5tKIJw', {
      foo: 'bar'
    }).addTo(map);
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

The GeoJson file is quite large so I will attach it into a mediafire download (along with the HTML, just incase you need it)

[Index.html](http://www.mediafire.com/file/9mm2bc3jn31z3lu/index.html)

[Trailheads GeoJson file](http://www.mediafire.com/file/8884gn49n2s89mo/trailheads.js)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that trailheads.js is a valid jsonp file, you should specify for each feature what information you will display. If you look at the [leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html#geojson), there's an option: 'onEachFeature' which you can use.

```
var trailheadsLayer = L.geoJson(trailheads, {
  onEachFeature: function(layer, feature) {
    feature.bindPopup('popup content');
  }
});
```

You can change 'popup content' for a property of your geoJSON, e.g. 'feature.properties.name'.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this however it is not currently working. could you please help some more? thank you so much. My latest reply has my current code

Comment: var trailheadsLayer = L.geoJson(trailheads, {
 onEachFeature: function(trailheadsLayer, feature) {
  feature.bindPopup(feature.properties.name);

 }
})

Comment: Can you log the names of the properties in the console by adding console.log(feature.properties.name); in the 'onEachFeature' function?

Comment: No, I get this error as seen in this screenshot http://imgur.com/a/tfnC2

Comment: EDIT: In that screenshot I accidently checked for feature.name.properties, when I fixed it (feature.properties.name) I get a similar error, Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: UPDATE #1: If I do feature.bindpopup(trailheads,name), inside of all of the popup boxes it displays "trailheads" because in my GeoJson file, trailheads is the variable assigned to the whole file and name is within the variable and the value of name is "trailheads". If I do feature.bindPopup(trailheads.type) what displays is "FeatureCollection". To really understand what I am saying open the GeoJson file and see what is associated with "Type" and "name". This proves that we atleast have it READING from the GeoJson file

Comment: UPDATE #2: However, If I do feature.bindPopup(trailheads.crs) or (trailheads.features) it gives me an error (e.g. whatever I put next to "trailheads." has more than one thing assigned to it, it will not display and gives me a node.appendChild error)

Comment: UPDATE #3: I discovered I needed to have something before I put in (trailheads.crs, trailheads.name etc....) I currently have it as "feature.bindPopup("name:" + trailheads.name)" and instead of giving me an error it gives me "Name: trailheads" so I tried it with trailheads.crs. Again, no error HOWEVER it displays "Name: [object Object]" instead and if I do trailheads.properties it does "Name: undefined". SO it IS reading it however it wont display the correct information for some reason